# What is balanced bagging in lightgbm?

Tags: lightgbm

The lightgbm [documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html?highlight=bagging_fraction#learning-control-parameters) mentions something called 'balanced bagging' under `pos_bagging_fraction` and `neg_bagging_fraction` but does not describe it.

> Note: if balanced bagging is enabled, bagging_fraction will be ignored

Can somebody help me understand what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They appear to be using the phrase "balanced bagging" to mean setting both `pos_bagging_fraction` and `neg_bagging_fraction`, i.e. you are bagging in a class-aware way to affect a balancing of the training data per tree.  Your quote supports this, saying that by setting `pos_bagging_fraction` and `neg_bagging_fraction`, the ordinary (class-unaware) `bagging_fraction` will be ignored.